# represent webpage as a class

Tags: java, oop

I was asked a question few days back and I am still not sure what is the proper answer to this question. I think I can create a class webpage and the members of the class can be HTML tags and there will be few methods which manipulate DOM elements. I am not sure if this question is too general or vague. Can you please provide your thoughts?

Note: This was asked in an interview for software developer.

Comment: I think answer might be related to [java servlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) .

Comment: @yilmazbahadir Not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Representing a real life object means to analyse its structure and create an abstract model for it.

A house for example is a rather complex object with doors, windows and levels and so on and to forth. But is has an network infrastructure and water installation and many many things more. You can start and identify the most important aspects of a house like doors and windows (or level).

A webpage is similar complex. It has an URL, a header, and a body, language, encoding, a purpose, incoming links, outgoing links.

Each of this items has their own specific aspects to describe them. So in your case, the interview question is aiming for such an object oriented analysis. There is no "right" answer to this but you can start with simple items:

```
Webpage:
 - url, java.lang URL
 - title, String
 - body, String or DOM
 - head, new type Header
 - outgoing links, List<Webpage>
 - incoming links, List<URL>
 - type, enum (static, dynamic)
```

and so on.

You would have to model a Header now.

This representation may have methods to manipulate the contents.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Can try thinking more about it now.